# Unique conditional count

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get a unique count with an inclusion and exclusion condition. Imagine I want to get counts per groupId when `place` is equals to `london` but not `paris`. The following is an example of different documents in the same index.

```
[
  {
    "groupId": 123,
    "place": "london"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 123,
    "place": "berlin"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 456,
    "place": "london"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 789,
    "place": "london"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 789,
    "place": "paris"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 789,
    "place": "berlin"
  },
  {
    "groupId": ABC,
    "place": "tokyo"
  }
]
```

Output should be similar to:

```
[
  {
    "groupId": 123,
    "count": "1"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 456,
    "count": "1"
  }
]
```

`"groupId": 789` is not included because there is one with `place` is `paris`, and `"groupId": "ABC"` is not included because it doesn't have any with `london`

Comment: is this data is part of single document as object field or diffrent document in index ?

Comment: good question @SagarPatel ; sorry for not clarifying it in the first place. They are different documents in the index. Edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used following aggregations

[1. Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

[2. filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

[3. Bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

In query section, I have filtered documents which have place as either London or Paris. This is to increase performance by removing documents which don't have either of these ex."groupId": "ABC"

In aggregation section, I have done a group by on groupId and then calculated count of London and Paris under it using filter aggregation. Using bucket selector I have only kept those group ids where count of London is at least 1 and count of Paris is zero.

**Query**

```
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "place": [
              "london",
              "paris"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "groupId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "london": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "place": "london"
            }
          }
        },
        "paris": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "place": "paris"
            }
          }
        },
        "buvket": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "paris_count": "paris>_count",
              "london_count": "london>_count"
            },
            "script": "params.paris_count==0 && params.london_count>=1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "groups" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 123,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "paris" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "london" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 456,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "paris" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "london" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```